# return types for clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags

Tags: go, kubernetes

I am trying to connect to a `kubernetes` client using `golang` and I saw this code:

```
var config, conferr = clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kube_config_path)
var clientset, cler = kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
```

What do `conferr` and `cler` give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [doc](https://godoc.org/k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd), both function return error object as the 2nd return value.

> func BuildConfigFromFlags(masterUrl, kubeconfigPath string) (*restclient.Config, error)
>
> func NewForConfig(c *rest.Config) (*Clientset, error)

So I believe the `conferr` there refer to the conf error. And `cler` refer to client error.

Both are `error` object.